# Book about a person with no physical body, being someone new every day

Tags: story-identification, books

It was about a person who had no physical body of their own. Every day, they became different people and were able to act as that person for the day. They had no control of who they could be, and couldn't be the same person twice, or for longer than a day.

Comment: Does this character take over the bodies of people who are already alive, obliterating the original personality?  Octavia Butler's character Doro in *Wild Seed* does that.

Comment: I've edited to reflect that you're looking for the book. If you want to ask about the mechanic of how it occurs (in-universe), it would be helpful if you could a) Confirm that my answer is correct and b) ask that as a separate question.

Comment: He doesn't fit the description completely, but I'd like to mention Croyd Crenson from "Wild Cards". Unlike most people infected with the Wild Card virus, Croyd didn't change just once. He gets a new appearance and new powers _every time he wakes up_. Because he's afraid of what the next transformation might bring, "The Sleeper" tries to stay awake as long as possible, by whatever means. When he finally sleeps, it may be for weeks or months. "Wild Cards" is an universe organized by George R. R. Martin in which more than 40 authors participated. Croyd is a brainchild of Roger Zelazny.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, Henning! I will check it out!

Comment: Now that we've identified the book that you were talking about, why not ask the second question about why A is jumping from body to body.

Comment: Ok. So why do you guys think A is jumping from body to body?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [*Every Day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Every_Day_(novel)) (2012) by David Levithan.

> Every Day is about the story of A, a person who wakes up occupying a different body each day. As described by Frank Bruni of The New York Times, "A. doesn't have a real name, presumably because they don't have a real existence: they're not a person, at least not in any conventional sense, but they have a spirit, switching without choice from one host to the next and, for just 24 hours, replacing its consciousness with their own." A has their own memories, but they are also able to tap into the memories of the person whose body they are occupying.

[image: book cover, shades of yellow and grey]

Comment: Yes. Could anyone explain how this may have happened? I would like some theories. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to have prompted DavidW to ask [a similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/208172/104486), but with more details. DavidW is obviously thinking of "The Safe-Deposit Box" in Greg Egan's short-story collection "Axiomatic" (1995), but your question is too vague to be sure of this.